# Should I delete my comment after OP fixes/golfs OP's code?

Tags: discussion, comments

I usually comment under an answer if I've found a mistake in the answerer's code. I also do it when the code can be golfed more.

After the answerer fixes/golfs his/her code, should I delete my comment?

Also, if the answerer has comment something like `Thanks!` replied to my comment, should I flag it as obsolete/not-constructive or something else after I've deleted my comment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Comments are generally not supposed to be permanent on Stack Exchange. In particular, if they suggest an improvement or critique something in an answer, they should be removed once the answer has addressed the comment. And also yes, since deleting your comment makes a "Thanks" reply obsolete, please also flag the answerer's comment so a moderator can clean it up.

As a side note, especially here on PPCG, this is why it's nice to credit any users who improved your score on a challenge, such that others can still see who improved it after the comments have been deleted.

Comment: So my comments like "_Your code fails for test case 2_"? should be removed as well, right? And if someone else posts the comment like that and the answerer fixes his/her code, should I flag it as obsolete?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes and yes. If the comment doesn't make sense in the context of the current version of the answer, it should be deleted, so feel free to flag others' comments as well if you find they are obsolete.

Comment: ok. Thanks! I guess it is time to flag some comments now ;-)

Comment: If comments aren't supposed to be permanent, then is there ever a case when comments shouldn't be deleted (after a period of time)?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes they could be deleted way more often than they are. But there are certainly exceptions. In particular, they might add something to the post that the OP is unwilling to edit into the post. (And of course we tend to turn a blind eye on the occasional witty comment that's funny enough to be preserved. ;))

Comment: @MartinBüttner For example, like your comment right there? :P